# Nginx Rewrite Directory-only

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I've the following rewrite into `server {}`:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]*)$ /Location.php?$1&$2&$3&$4&$5&$6&$7&$8&$9&$10;
```

My **Location.php** is inside the **register** folder. How I do to run this rule only when the visitor is in the **register** directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply add /register ? like

```
rewrite ^/register/([^/]*)$ /register/Location.php?$1&$2&$3&$4&$5&$6&$7&$8&$9&$10 break;
```

and how come `Location.php` is inside `register` folder yet you wrote `/Location.php` not `/register/Location.php`

Comment: And if I add /register/Location.php, works! But returns redirect loop error.

Comment: my bad, add break at the end

Comment: Almost! The loop problem is: `/register/Enter` redirects to `/register/index.php?action?=enter`. You've no idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: well if its going to `index.php` not `Location.php` then it could be some other rewrite rule or something.